# Why is Mifare Classic data readable with KeyB in transport configuration?

Tags: authentication, nfc, mifare

The [Mifare Classic specification from NXP](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MF1S50YYX_V1.pdf) explicitly states, that data should not be readable using KeyB when using transport configuration (factory default), because KeyB is readable (having KeyA) by itself.

> **8.7.2 Access conditions for the sector trailer**
> [...] On chip delivery the access conditions for the sector trailers and key A are predefined as transport configuration. *Since key B may be read in the transport configuration, new cards must be authenticated with key A.*

> **8.7.3 Access conditions for data blocks**
> [...] Key management: *in transport configuration key A must be used for authentication*

> **Table 8 footnote for transport configuration**:
> *If key B may be read in the corresponding Sector Trailer it cannot serve for authentication* (see grey marked lines in Table 7). As a consequences, if the reader authenticates any block of a sector which uses such access conditions for the Sector
> Trailer and using key B, the card will refuse any subsequent memory access after authentication.

However, when I change KeyA from default to a custom key, I am still able to read the data using default KeyB (FF FF FF FF FF FF).

I am using the Android NXP Tag-Info tool to test the cards that I am writing from a custom application:

```
Sector 5 (0x05)
[14] rwi  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF |................|
[15] rwi  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF |................|
[16] rwi  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF |................|
[17] wxx  XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX FF:07:80 69 FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF
          (unknown key)                 Factory default key (readable)
```

You can see, that the sector is in its default transport configuration (FF:07:80) and that the application does not know Key A. But the App was able to read the content of all data blocks (all FF here, but it also correctly shows custom data).

From the specification, I would've totally assumed, that if I use default configuration, KeyA is mandatory to read data.

<strike>When I also change KeyB to the custom key of KeyA, I am no longer able to access the card, except when explicitly using KeyA.

Is it an exception when KeyB is still default? That would be a security risk.</strike> - I made a mistake while testing. Its actually also possible to access the card using KeyB if it is different from default.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it seems to be an issue with the brand. The chip manufacturer of the cards I was testing so far is Fudan Microelectronics Co. Ltd.

I obtained an original NXP tag and it works according to the specifications from the datasheet. It was not possible to authenticate with KeyB in transport configuration.

This can be a serious security issue, if you are unaware of this and switch from NXP to Fudan.

As [mentioned here](http://www.cs.ru.nl/%7Ewouter/papers/2008-thebest.pdf):

> The Fudan chip is an unlicensed clone (“counterfeit”) produced by the China-based company Fudan Microelectronics Co. Ltd.

I found a ["functional specification" from Fudan](https://www.myplastikkarten.de/FILE/Tipografie/62/Contenuti/Download/sheet-rfid-karten-fudan-f08-1k-data-sheet-grafik-info.pdf). It doesn't mention the transport configuration or the KeyA/KeyB related access at all. At least they do not make false statements I guess.

Other manufacturers like SonMicro Elektronik stay true to the specifications from NXP:

[image]

**So carefully look at the specification if you change to a different chip manufacturer!**

Comment: I am pretty sure I ended up with the same or similar chips in some tags I got. Did you ever find out any more details on this implementation of the access control bits? From your example it looks like the only thing that requires KeyA is actually reading KeyA itself (though I suppose you only tested reading and not writing). Did you find any configuration under which providing KeyA is enforced for any operation?

Comment: @tgies Our quick fix for this was, to change our "driver" to write a random value into the KeyB register if it still holds the default key. So the next time a card is updated/written, the card can no longer be accessed by just trying the default KeyB.